# Using @ModelAttribute on a method argument

Tags: java, spring-mvc

As said at this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) under section 
*Using @ModelAttribute on a method argument*

> An @ModelAttribute on a method argument indicates the argument should
>   be retrieved from the model.

But i have observed that even without annotating UserDetail with @ModelAttribute , userDetail is populated correctly. Here is relevant code snippet

```
<form:form id="userForm" action="path/userDetail" method="post" commandName="userDetail">

    @RequestMapping(value="/userDetail", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processUserDetail(UserDetail userDetail, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) 
    {}
```

So my question does spring itself populate the project custom objects (in this case userDetail) present in handler method arguments
even without annotating @ModelAttribute. I believe @ModelAttribute plays role while rendering view but while submission spring 
automatically populates the  method argument if it is present in model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TLDR

When all you care is to populate an instance of your own type it doesn't matter.

### Long version

In most cases it doesn't make a difference if you add `@ModelAttribute` or omit it. As @MasterSlave already mentioned the same mechanism is used behind the scenes. Before I talk about when it's important to use `@ModelAttribute` let me explain what the model actually is.

From the point of a view, that is being rendered, it's the data that can be accessed by the view. In your case the `userDetail`. The controller is responsible to add all necessary data to the model. There are many ways to achieve that. `@ModelAttribute` is one of them.

One use case for explicitly using `@ModelAttribute` is to define the key by which the data can be accessed. `@ModelAttribute("user") UserDetail user` let's the view access the data by the key `user`. Otherwise it would be `userDetail`.

The data may also already exist **before** the controller method is called. Maybe it's stored in the session or generated by another method. That's what is meant by

> the argument should be retrieved from the model

But it may exist under a specific key, like "user".  So again, you have to provide the name via `@ModelAttribute("user")`. The existing data could also be a "simple" type, like a `String` or a `Date`. In that case `@ModelAttribute` is necessary to retrieve the data from the model.

The same is true for arguments of types that would be handled by other resolvers, like `Map` or `Locale`.

Answer (score 1):

**Does handler method resolves arguments even without annotating @ModelAttribute?**

Yes, but what *@ModelAttribute* changes is the point when an appropriate resolving happens. What the framework does in the process of argument resolving is it takes each argument and iterates through the list of registered resolvers and once that it finds the first resolver that supports the argument it resolves it and moves to the next argument.

The resolver that handles model attributes is [ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html). And it is registered two times, first time scanning only the arguments annotated with the @ModelAttribute, and the second time as a last in the list, resolving the arguments even if not annotated.

The list and the order of resolver you can check by checking the source of the [RequestMappingHandlerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html). Note the two registrations of the [ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html), the *true*/*false* parameters determines if the annotation is mandatory or not

```
private List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> getDefaultArgumentResolvers() {
    List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>();

    // Annotation-based argument resolution
    resolvers.add(new RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory(), false));
    resolvers.add(new RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new MatrixVariableMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new MatrixVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor(false));
    resolvers.add(new RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(getMessageConverters()));
    resolvers.add(new RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver(getMessageConverters()));
    resolvers.add(new RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory()));
    resolvers.add(new RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory()));
    resolvers.add(new ExpressionValueMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory()));

    // Type-based argument resolution
    resolvers.add(new ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new ServletResponseMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new HttpEntityMethodProcessor(getMessageConverters()));
    resolvers.add(new RedirectAttributesMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new ModelMethodProcessor());
    resolvers.add(new MapMethodProcessor());
    resolvers.add(new ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new SessionStatusMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new UriComponentsBuilderMethodArgumentResolver());

    // Custom arguments
    if (getCustomArgumentResolvers() != null) {
        resolvers.addAll(getCustomArgumentResolvers());
    }

    // Catch-all
    resolvers.add(new RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory(), true));
    resolvers.add(new ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor(true));

    return resolvers;
}
```

Comment: _So the risk ... is that it can be matched by some other resolver_ - And which one might that be?

Comment: I'm not able to find the example, so I've removed it from the response